# MySql query monthly return 0 if null

Tags: mysql

My query is okay if I don't place a where clause. But I must have the where clause because I will get the monthly total by user. Below is my query:

```
SELECT IFNULL(count(PropertyId), 0) AS Total, a.monthLead
FROM (SELECT 'May' monthLead, 1 monthOrder UNION ALL SELECT 'Jun' monthLead, 2 monthOrder UNION ALL SELECT 'Jul' monthLead, 3 monthOrder UNION ALL SELECT 'Aug' monthLead, 4 monthOrder UNION ALL SELECT 'Sep' monthLead, 5 monthOrder UNION ALL SELECT 'Oct' monthLead, 6 monthOrder UNION ALL SELECT 'Nov' monthLead, 7 monthOrder UNION ALL SELECT 'Dec' monthLead, 8 monthOrder) a
LEFT JOIN leads b ON a.monthLead = DATE_FORMAT(b.DateEntered, '%b')
LEFT JOIN users_leads c ON c.LeadId = b.PropertyId
WHERE c.UserId = 78 AND b.IsRecordDeleted = 0
AND DATE_FORMAT(b.DateEntered, '%b') IN ('May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec')
GROUP BY a.monthLead, year(b.DateEntered), month(b.DateEntered)
ORDER BY a.monthOrder, b.DateEntered
```

Output is:

```
-----------------------
-- Total | monthLead --
-- 2     | May       --
-- 2     | Sep       --
-----------------------
```

It should be:

```
-----------------------
-- Total | monthLead --
-- 2     | May       -- 
-- 0     | Jun       --
-- 0     | Jul       --
-- 0     | Aug       --
-- 2     | Sep       --
-- 0     | Nov       --
-- 0     | Dec       --
-----------------------
```

I have change `AND` to `OR` but it is not correct. If I used `OR` it will get the other user's leads.

Here is the SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/acf86/2

Anyone can help me out?

Thanks

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) explaining the issue and replicating the current behavior?

Comment: @MostyMostacho here is the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/acf86/2

Comment: What about http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/acf86/24 ? It's not very clear what you're trying to achieve semantically, but I [noticed](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/acf86/19), the left join generates records with valid PropertyID but _null_ UserID.

Comment: Ignore that; please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be what you want:

```
SELECT IFNULL(count(b.PropertyId), 0) AS Total, a.monthLead
FROM (SELECT 'May' monthLead, 1 monthOrder UNION ALL SELECT 'Jun' monthLead, 2 monthOrder UNION ALL SELECT 'Jul' monthLead, 3 monthOrder UNION ALL SELECT 'Aug' monthLead, 4 monthOrder UNION ALL SELECT 'Sep' monthLead, 5 monthOrder UNION ALL SELECT 'Oct' monthLead, 6 monthOrder UNION ALL SELECT 'Nov' monthLead, 7 monthOrder UNION ALL SELECT 'Dec' monthLead, 8 monthOrder) a
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT b.DateEntered, b.PropertyId /*, c.UserId, b.IsRecordDeleted -- not necessary*/
  FROM leads b, users_leads c
  WHERE c.PropertyId = b.PropertyId
  AND c.UserId = 78 AND b.IsRecordDeleted = 0
  AND DATE_FORMAT(b.DateEntered, '%b') IN ('May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec')
) b ON a.monthLead = DATE_FORMAT(b.DateEntered, '%b')
GROUP BY a.monthLead, year(b.DateEntered), month(b.DateEntered)
ORDER BY a.monthOrder, b.DateEntered
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/acf86/35

Also to note, the following line is not necessary:

```
AND DATE_FORMAT(b.DateEntered, '%b') IN ('May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec')
```

since the records will get filtered anyway by `a.monthLead = DATE_FORMAT(b.DateEntered, '%b')`.

The basic semantic idea is to be really careful about what you're outer-joining with. In my query, I have only used one left join, because I want to inner-join the input tables and ensure that **when there's no record from leads, there will be no record from user_leads**.

This result is then left-joined with your *in-query* table A to generate *null* records when there's no record from the inner join query.

Comment: I will be using this one.. since it is much faster in executing the query. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to know it's faster and it helped you. When you say _it works_, are you sure it works for all possible input data (and not just for some fringe case)? I only corrected your original query based on my best understanding of the fiddle you posted. **Also,** you may want to consider using the month number (`ORDER BY MONTH(b.DateEntered)`) to do the ordering, rather than using your in-query table A. It's generally considered bad design and re-invention of wheel to do what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT IFNULL(count(c.PropertyId), 0) AS Total, a.monthLead
FROM (SELECT 'May' monthLead, 1 monthOrder UNION ALL SELECT 'Jun' monthLead, 2 monthOrder UNION ALL SELECT 'Jul' monthLead, 3 monthOrder UNION ALL SELECT 'Aug' monthLead, 4 monthOrder UNION ALL SELECT 'Sep' monthLead, 5 monthOrder UNION ALL SELECT 'Oct' monthLead, 6 monthOrder UNION ALL SELECT 'Nov' monthLead, 7 monthOrder UNION ALL SELECT 'Dec' monthLead, 8 monthOrder) a
LEFT JOIN leads b ON a.monthLead = DATE_FORMAT(b.DateEntered, '%b')
LEFT JOIN users_leads c ON c.PropertyId = b.PropertyId AND c.UserId = 78 AND b.IsRecordDeleted = 0
AND DATE_FORMAT(b.DateEntered, '%b') IN ('May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec')
GROUP BY a.monthLead, year(b.DateEntered), month(b.DateEntered)
ORDER BY a.monthOrder, b.DateEntered
```

All I did was changing the `where` to an `and` and `count(c.PropertyId)` to `count(b.PropertyId)`.

As a side note, doesn't this return the same values as the above query and is a bit easier to read?

```
SELECT COUNT(ul.PropertyId) Total, m.monthLead
FROM (
  SELECT 'May' monthLead, 5 monthOrder UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Jun', 6 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Jul', 7 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Aug', 8 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Sep', 9 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Oct', 10 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Nov', 11 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Dec', 12) m
LEFT JOIN leads l ON m.monthOrder = month(l.DateEntered) AND l.IsRecordDeleted = 0 AND month(l.DateEntered) >= 5
LEFT JOIN users_leads ul ON ul.PropertyId = l.PropertyId AND ul.UserId = 78
GROUP BY m.monthOrder, year(l.DateEntered)
ORDER BY m.monthOrder, l.DateEntered
```

Comment: This answer will also do. Thanks!